# How to declare New-Signal-Slot syntax in Qt 5 as a parameter to function

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, signals-slots

How can I pass signal or slot (member-function, new syntax in Qt 5) as a parameter to function and then call `connect`?

e.g. I want to write a function that waits for a signal.

**Note**: It is not compile - `PointerToMemberFunction` is my question.

```
bool waitForSignal(const QObject* sender, PointerToMemberFunction??? signal, int timeOut = 5000/*ms*/)
{
  if (sender == nullptr)
    return true;
  bool isTimeOut = false;
  QEventLoop loop;
  QTimer timer;
  timer.setSingleShot(true);
  QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout,
    [&loop, &isTimeOut]()
    {
      loop.quit();
      isTimeOut = true;
    });
  timer.start(timeOut);
  QObject::connect(sender, signal, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
  loop.exec();
  timer.stop();
  return !isTimeOut;
}
```

Is there any way to pass list of signals to this function for connection?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no public API for this. Sure, you can simply peek at the code and see the trick (for instance see [here](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/350c60b79e720d005a1a554fd177dbda607079cf:src/corelib/kernel/qtimer.h#L84) for QTimer), but unfortunately that's private APIs (= use at your own risk, we can break them at any time, etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should create template:

```
template<typename Func>
void waitForSignal(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func>::Object *sender, Func signal) {
    QEventLoop loop;
    connect(sender, signal, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
    loop.exec();
}
```

Usage:

```
waitForSignal(button, &QPushButton::clicked);
```

Comment: Works, but see my comment above. This is private API.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `QSignalSpy` to wait for a signal to be emitted by :

```
QSignalSpy spy(sender, SIGNAL(someSignal()));
spy.wait(timeOut);
```

Or (This is possible in Qt 5.4) :

```
QSignalSpy spy(sender, &SomeObject::someSignal);
spy.wait(timeOut);
```

If you want to implement it in a function :

```
bool waitForSignal(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func>::Object *sender, Func signal, int timeOut = 5000/*ms*/)
{
   QSignalSpy spy(sender, signal);
   return spy.wait(timeOut);
}
```

Do not forget to add the relevant module in qmake :

```
QT += testlib
```

Comment: You're not supposed to use `QSignalSpy` (or in general `QtTest`) in application code.

Comment: @peppe There is nothing wrong with using it as it works and there is not any other way which is more straightforward.