# A function wrapper around QObject::connect

Tags: c++, qt, templates, lambda, signals-slots

I'm trying to write a function which passes its arguments to `QObject::connect`.

```
template <typename Func1, typename Func2>
void addConnection(const QObject* sender, Func1 signal, Func2 slot)
{
    m_connections.push_back(QObject::connect(sender, signal, slot));
}
```

and here is how I'm calling it:

```
addConnection(&m_scannerSystem, &ScannerSystem::signalStatus, [=](int status){ this->onStatusChanged(status); });
```

This results in an error:

```
'QObject::connect' : none of the 4 overloads could convert all the argument types
```

but I'm not able to figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: why are you passing by value?

Comment: @deW1  I'm passing function pointers, why wouldn't I pass them by value? QObject::connect has the same signature.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to declare New-Signal-Slot syntax in Qt 5 as a parameter to function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27756321/how-to-declare-new-signal-slot-syntax-in-qt-5-as-a-parameter-to-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You problem is that you are trying to pass a pointer to QObject but how in that case you would be able to call a member function of the other object(ScannerSysterm in your case)? The system has to know the actual type of the passed sender. So you might fix it this way:

```
template <typename Sender, typename Func1, typename Func2>
void addConnection(const Sender* sender, Func1 signal, Func2 slot)
{
    QObject::connect(sender, signal, slot);
}
```

Or by using some magic Qt traits:

```
template <typename Func1, typename Func2>
void addConnection(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func1>::Object* sender, Func1 signal, Func2 slot)
{
    QObject::connect(sender, signal, slot);
}
```

Comment: Ah, of course, I assumed there was something wrong with passing the lambda and totally missed that. I also like your solution as it doesn't have to use Qt's private API.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the compiler error message? The compiler doesn't know a suitable `QObject::connect()` function among 5 overload functions.
[QT doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect)

If you use below code, compile will success.

```
addConnection( &m_scannerSystem, SIGNAL( signalStatus( int ) ), this, SLOT( onStatusChanged( int ) ) );
```

Comment: I can't use this overload to connect to a lambda. I'm using new Qt 5 syntax:https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

Comment: I don't understand why you only use a lambda.  I think the lambda is not mandatory in this situation. Am I wrong?